# How can I draw and rotate an Arrow at an Orientation in 3D Space?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-animation, catransform3d

I want to draw an image like the following in a certain orientation.

[image]

Assume that the device lies flat on a table the image above shows how the arrow should be drawn. The angle between the device and the table is called `alpha` and it is zero in this case. The arrow points straight to a predefined location point. If you rotate the device on the table the arrow will point alway to the target direction just like a compass.

I did the update of the image position with the following code in 2D space:

```
// Create the image for the compass
let arrowImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100))
arrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: "arrow.png")
self.view.addSubview(arrowImageView)
arrowImageView.center = self.view.center


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading!) {

    var direction: Float = Float(newHeading.magneticHeading)

    if direction > 180 {
      direction = 360 - direction
    }
    else {
      direction = 0 - direction
    }

    // Rotate the arrow image
    if let arrowImageView = self.arrowImageView {
      UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        arrowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(self.degreesToRadians(direction) + self.angle))

      })
    }

    let currentLocation: CLLocation = manager.location
}
```

However if the device is lifted up from the table the value of alpha increases (`alpha > 0`). The arrow image should still point to the target location but should be drawn in perspective keeping the alpha angle into account. Here is how this looks from the side.

[image]

The only thing which changes in 3D space is the `alpha` angle. All other angles remain constant.

**How can I draw and rotate an Arrow image at an Orientation (given alpha angle) in 3D Space?**

Comment: Your question is flawed. Try opening the compass app with the device face down. Use a glass table if you need. That's alpha at 180 degrees in your parlance. Rotate to portrait mode — alpha of 90. The only thing you've changed is alpha. Has the displayed heading stayed the same? Should it have stayed the same? That's a direct reporting of the CoreLocation heading. So is it true to say that "The only thing which changes i. 3D space is the alpha angle. All other angles remain constant."? Look up gimbal lock. Trying to model full 3d orientation with angles is a dead end. It doesn't work.

Comment: did you draw the 3D arrow? I want to make this as well, would you like to share your solution?