# Angle of iPhone Position

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, position

How to calculate iPhone position angle from 0 to 360 degrees. Considering portrait as 0 degrees? I tired using gyroscope and accelerometer, but I am unable to get the angle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine the Device Orientation and its resulting Angle on one Dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643276/determine-the-device-orientation-and-its-resulting-angle-on-one-dimension)

Comment: Compass angle? Or are you talking yaw, pitch, or roll angle? You should be able to use the accellerometer for those since the force of gravity will

Comment: i am taking the accelerometer x,y,z values. and calculatinf atan(y/x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {

```
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (motion, error) in

    let radians = atan2((motion?.gravity.x)!, (motion?.gravity.y)!) - .pi

    let degrees = radians * 180.0  / .pi

    print(-degrees)

}
```

}